# Caching large ActiveRecord objects with Dalli

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord, store, dalli

I can't cache large ActiveRecord objects. With small ones it's ok:

```
sel = Car.select("id, `key`, value").limit(1000)
Rails.cache.write('miauuu', sel)
=> true
```

But if they get a bit larger:

```
sel = Car.select("id, `key`, value").limit(10000)
Rails.cache.write('miauuu', sel)
=> false
```

The size is **not terribly high** though:

```
ObjectSpace.memsize_of(sel)
=> 272
```

I'm using **Dalli** cache store:

```
Rails.application.config.cache_store
 => :dalli_store
```

I even ensured the max value should be large enough in **production.rb** has this:

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store, { value_max_bytes: 2000000 }
```

And yet, I'm getting false here:

```
Rails.cache.write('miauuu', sel)
=> false
```

Any idea why? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to also update the Memcached config on the server, usually located in /etc/memcached.conf with the correct setting, in your case:

```html
-I 2M
```